# TypeError: Cannot destructure property of undefined when using axios

Tags: javascript, node.js, axios

I'm running into a very weird issue that I didnt find an answer for online.

Here's my method:

```
export const loginUser = (handleOrEmail, password) => {
  const config = {
    headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
    }
  };

  const body = JSON.stringify({ handleOrEmail, password });

  try {
    const { data } = await axios.post(
      "http://localhost:5000/api/auth",
      body,
      config
    );

    console.log("data received!", data);
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(
      "Err caught logging in!",
      (err.response && err.response.data) || err
    );
  }
};
```

And my node route:

```
router.post("/", (req, res) => {
  console.log("entered?");
  const { handleOrEmail, password } = req.body;

  return res.json({ msg: "backend reached!", handleOrEmail, password });
});
```

It prints `entered`, but `req.body` is undefined. Why is this happening? `GET` requests work, (and so do POST request, apparently, but the body is undefined).

Comment: have you added bodyparser?

Comment: Please add that as an answer, I didnt find it on SO for me

Comment: Fixed with `app.use(express.json({ extended: false }));`

Comment: was it bodyparser or express.json?

Comment: Express added body-parser into their framework. I just forgot to use it. Could be solved by using body parser, but express already includes it as a dependency

Comment: aa I see, cool stuff